# Can I get a method by signature, using reflection?

Tags: c#, function, reflection

In C++, we can scan through the memory to get the function by some assembly pattern, I'm thinking about that if we can have a relevant ways to get the function by using function signature in .Net, and if could, post an example.

Comment: Why is this tagged "C#" when you are asking about "C++"?

Comment: There's no reflection in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx) overloaded method:

```
 public MethodInfo GetMethod(
    string name,
    Type[] types
)
```

> Searches for the specified public method whose parameters match the specified argument types.

You could find examples in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I wanted to get the method without name specified.